# Relations between Trace and Spectrum of an Operator

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, operator-theory, trace

As the trace of a matrix equals to the sum of all eigenvalues, do we have an analogous result that the trace of an operator (if it is well-defined) equals to an integral on the spectrum space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that you're after [Lidskii's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_class#Lidskii.27s_theorem). It states that if $H$ is a separable Hilbert space, if $A\colon H\longrightarrow H$ is an operator of trace class, and if $\{\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\ldots\}$ are the eigenvalues of $A$ (enumerated with algebraic multiplicities taken into account), then$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\lambda_n=\operatorname{Tr}(A).$$Note that the previous sum may well be just a finite sum.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think operators of trace class are compact operators and thus have countable spectrum if I'm right? So this result is not extremely surprising. What also interests me is, for example, the irrational rotation operator $Vf(t)=f(t-\theta)$ on $L^2(\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})$, whose spectrum is the whole unit circle and the trace is exactly $\int e^{2\pi it}dt=0.$ Is there any deeper explanation for this?

Comment: @Fan No. The definition is: a trace class operator is a compact operator $A$ such that, for some orthonormal basis $(e_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ of $H$, the sum $\sum_n\langle (A^*A)^{1/2} e_n, e_n \rangle$ converges. Yes, the set of eigenvalues is countable, but that is not part of the definition. I don't know the answer to your question.